# Visual Studio 2015 is default to P4VS even though solution is controlled by git

Tags: git, visual-studio, perforce

About 2 years ago our company switched from Perforce to Git.  I've been using the Git plugin in Visual Studio 2015 without any problems since then. Just in the last month or so when I start Visual Studio on any project, I receive the message

> The active solution or project is controlled by a different source control plug-in than the one you have selected. If you change the source control plug-in, the active solution or project will be closed.

If I say yes, my solution is closed. If I then look at Tools / Options / Source Control, the plug-in is set to P4VS.

If I say no, my solution is left open, and the source code control is Git.

I've tried creating a Visual Studio project from scratch, controlled by Git, and I get the same results.  This is a simple empty project.  I've examined the .sln and .csproj files, and there are no source code control keys in either one.

If I simply open up Visual Studio without a project, my source control plug-in is set to Git.

It seems Visual Studio has decided that my projects are all controlled by  Perforce and is considering Git to be a change, but I can't figure out how it is deciding this. Obviously, I can just click "No" and proceed but I'd like to fix this if I can.

Comment: Open your project file in a text editor and remove any Perforce references (`SccProvider`, `SccProvider0 ` and stuff like that).

Comment: @CodeCaster Thanks but there are no scc keys or perforce / p4 lines in either my csproj or sln files.

Comment: @DaveG make a backup of your solution user options (**.suo**) file and remove it from the VS solution. Does it help?

Comment: I am getting the same annoying message when opening non-Perforce controlled solutions. I am currently using both AnkhSVN and P4VS for source control of different projects. I may uninstall P4VS and suggest my company not to migrate to it, just because of this nuisance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we don't use perforce anymore, I finally went into tools -> Extension and disabled P4VS (Perforce).  That seems to have solved the problem.

As a side benefit, I was also having trouble where I'd try to delete a file from a project in VS, not get an error message, but the file wouldn't be deleted.  When I disabled P4VS that problem seems to have gone away also.

Note: the issue was not due to the .suo file or anything in the .proj file, as I determined by removing the .suo and by creating a fresh, empty project and examining the .proj.

Answer (score 0):

This looks similar to a problem describe [Migrating from AnkhSVN to VisualSVN](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00058/) (AnkhSVN and VisualSVN are plug-ins for Visual Studio that add support for SVN, but the same should also work for other source control plug-ins). If that's your case, you can try the following:

- remove the solution user options (**.suo**) file from your solution and restart Visual Studio,
- open your VS project files with a text editor, remove the following lines; restart Visual Studio and reopen your solution:

> ```
> <SccProjectName>XXXX</SccProjectName>
> <SccLocalPath>XXXX</SccLocalPath>
> <SccAuxPath>XXXX</SccAuxPath>
> <SccProvider>XXXX</SccProvider>
> ```

Comment: Unfortunately the problem isn't related to a particular solution.  I've tried creating a new solution, removing the suo file, and making sure that the project file doesn't contain any Scc entries at all, and I still have the same problem.

Comment: @DaveG have you tried repairing this VS2015 installation (this may take some time to complete)? Start **appwiz.cpl**, locate your VS2015 on the list and, right-click it and select Change (or Repair).